# System.Transactions.TransactionStateInDoubt.EndCommit(InternalTransaction tx) : Exception Thrown C# .Net

Tags: c#, .net

i wanted to make multiple api calls in foreach,

```
foreach (var item in array)
            {
                var url = item.Value + item.Key;
                client.BaseAddress = new Uri(url);
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(
                new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

                response = client.GetAsync(url).Result;
            }
```

First api calls go with no problem, in second loop this error occured. couldnt find out why, 
Note : this array is key value pair (Dictionary).

Comment: won't calling `Result` explicitly make this API call to wait for the result?

Answer (score 0):

this issue can be fixed when u use Task list and add each url to the list as a task.